# Botões carregando valor unico em react

Tags: react

olá, eu estou com uma dúvida que esta me matando a horas!!
Meu codigo em react, é sobre ao clicar no botao 'um' mostrasse uma imagem, e ao clicar no botão 'dois' mudasse para outra imagem. So que não estou conseguindo fazer com que o react entenda que estou clicando em outro botão. Queria que uma unica função fizesse isso, mudando apenas esse valor/variavel da função para armazenar essa nova imagem, mas não sei como a função(useState) vai receber esse valor = imagem . Sem que precisasse criar uma função diferente para cada botão. E cada botão recebendo seu valor/imagem unico(ja tentei mudar passando propriedades).[mudando imagem com botoes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQ5aA.png)

Answer (score -2):

Olá, você pode usar o poder dos hooks (useState) para lidar com as mudanças de url da imagem ao clicar no botão, usando o mesmo método:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  // Defina o estado inicial para a imagem padrão
  const [imagem, setImagem] = useState('url_da_imagem_padrao.jpg');

  // Função para mudar a imagem com base no botão clicado
  const mudarImagem = (novaImagem) => {
    setImagem(novaImagem);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Lógica a ser executada quando a imagem for alterada
    console.log('Imagem alterada para:', imagem);
  }, [imagem]);

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Botão Um */}
      <button onClick={() => mudarImagem('url_da_imagem_um.jpg')}>Um</button>

      {/* Botão Dois */}
      <button onClick={() => mudarImagem('url_da_imagem_dois.jpg')}>Dois</button>

      {/* Exibição da Imagem */}
      <img src={imagem} alt="Imagem exibida" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: ahh mt obg, era um erro tao bobo! estava passando a nova imagem como props, não como argumento para a função a ser chamada!! agradeço!!!